# Select text on focus does not work for multiline textInputs

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

The text inside my multiline textInput is not being selected even though 'selectTextOnFocus' is set to true.

I know that the text will be selected if multiline is not set to true, but I want this textInput to have multiple lines. I read the React Native docs for textInput but did not see anything to address this problem I am facing.

```java
<TextInput placeholder={'test'} multiline={true} selectTextOnFocus={true}/>
```

I expect to click on the multiline textInput and have the text selected on focus.

I am using React Native version 0.59 and running the code on the latest iOS on both my iPhone 7+ and iPad 6th gen.

Comment: It does show select text popup but you have to long press on it